# Is it possible to do live text-replace in shell (zsh)?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, zsh

Is there a way to replace text while typing in terminal. I run ocaml interpreter and it gets a little stale typing `function` so many times. Is there a way to replace text shortcut with a longer version in terminal? `alias` won't work because I need to press enter, I want to be live as I type. I use `oh-my-zsh`. For example typing `fn` and then space should put `function` in terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this is on topic for Stack Overflow, but you should probably look at the smart tab completion scripts (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html). You may do better on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can do it with your term shortcut, for example using .Xresources with `URxvt.keysym.M-C-f:` for `alt+ctrl+f`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited for Unix & Linux SE!

Comment: If you're in the Ocaml interpreter, you're not in the shell any more.

Comment: You say `bash` in the title, but the question says you're using `oh-my-zsh`. Which are you really asking about? Or neither, because you're really asking about Ocaml?

Comment: @Barmar I don't think OP understands the distinctions between bash/zsh/interactive interpreter.

Comment: I am using ```zsh``` on OSX. I think the solutions could be similar. For example, there is keyboard shortcut in ```OSX``` which are useful but they don't run in shell or chrome I can run them on ```Notes``` though. So really am wondering why isn't this implemented in the OS level to replace shortcuts everywhere.

Comment: @CupOfCoffee There are only a limited number of common keystrokes. It is a purposeful design decision to have keystroke bindings implemented at the application level.

Comment: bash and zsh are very different shells. Tag for one or the other, but not both. And **definitely** don't put bash in the title if zsh is the shell you care about.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language-specific interpreters are separate from the shell.

If your Ocaml interpreter supports GNU `readline`, it might be possible to have some sort of tab completion hook. For example, the Python interactive interpreter uses `readline` and `rlcompleter` to have this kind of functionality by default: https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#rlcompleter-config

I have no OCaml experience, but a quick Google found [this](https://github.com/diml/utop), which might interest you.